# Generating and Confirming Timestamp on P2P Network

Tags: algorithm, p2p

I'm planning to code a P2P network. In this network each client can create a record and share it with the others. You can think this like Bitcoin's transactions. Generating the record and sharing it OK.

But, I want to add a timestamp on the record too, my problem is about confirming the time stamp.

Each client can create a record with a timestamp but how can the others be sure that this time stamp is correct? How to confirm that timestamp on the record and records create time is the same?

Can you please give me a advice?

Answer (score 1):

That is not directly possible. You will have to expect wrongly set times on your client’s computers anyways. You can’t guarantee “correct” timestamps without a central server. What you *can* do is secure that a claimed order is true, by adding a hash of the previous record to the current record.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement time stamping inside p2p network. So when client creates a record, sends it to k other clients (of n alltogether). Each of them time stamps record with his local time. If network is big enough this is trusted timestamping.